# Looking for the 'Mastering XPages' supporting applications

Tags: xpages

The supporting applications used to be at [www.ibmpressbooks.com/title/9780133373370](http://www.ibmpressbooks.com/title/9780133373370).  But since IBM sold Notes, it is no longer there.  Does anyone know where I can download these Chp??Ed2.nsf files?

Comment: Thanks Per for this link.  Now I can learn xpages much easier.

Comment: Good to hear, Merlin. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please mark my answer as accepted: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Thanks

Comment: Now I am looking for com.example.library.  I am running version 9.0.  Is that the problem?

Comment: Where is com.example.library referenced? and what is the problem?

Comment: Mastering XPages, page 749 recommends downloading exampleLibraryFiles.zip

Comment: You can find it here: https://ds-infolib.hcltechsw.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/page.xsp?documentId=718903A9304D0F448525772A00325901&action=openDocument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still download from the book page at https://www.informit.com/store/mastering-xpages-a-step-by-step-guide-to-xpages-application-9780133373370. The download links to https://www.informit.com/content/images/9780133373370/downloads/9780133373370_Code-Samples.zip which still works. The zip contains 25 files.